# Derivative of $x\mapsto x \sin y(x)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I differentiate $x\sin(y)$ with respect to $x$ normally then what happens to the $\sin(y)$? In partial differentiation it's taken as constant thus, partially differentiating with respect to $x$ would give the result as $\sin( y)$.  I want to know what happens when you differentiate normally e.g. $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: What does the arrow mean in title in my edited version of question?

Comment: Read it as "maps to."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $y$ is a function of $x$,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin y + x\cos y \frac{dy}{dx} $$

In other words, you're just applying the product rule (and chain rule since $y$ is a function of $x$): Assume $v$ is a function of $g$ which is a function of $x$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(u(x)v(g(x))) = v(g(x))\frac{du}{dx} + u(x)\frac{dv}{dg}\cdot\frac{dg}{dx}$$

Comment: Product rule, not chain rule.

Comment: @Deepak, Of course!

Comment: Can anyone confirm why does the other answer says to use both product and chain rule?

Comment: To differentiate $\sin y$, you need to differentiate $\sin$ which gives you cosine and then differentiate $y$ wrt $x$ which is $y'(x)$. You then multiply these two together to give you the actual derivative of $\sin y$.

Comment: @Deepak, quite an interesting profile by the way! Medical Doctor by day, mathematician/physicist by night! Why not train as a radiologist?

Comment: @John: It appears you only applied the product rule in your answer.

Comment: @user121335, I used both product rule and chain rule. You can read more about product rule and chain rule here-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule.

Comment: I don't know why the other upvoted answer looks so different but I find yours more cleaner.

Comment: @John Haha, perhaps too much info in my profile. Frankly, radiologists don't use much math in their daily lives. It's just reading boring old films. The math behind MRI and CTs, especially 3-D reconstruction is nice, but they're not the engineers designing the stuff. On the contrary, in my field (Microbiology), some measure of scientific rigour is used almost daily (validation, quality control, statistical sampling), not to mention the math behind bacterial kill kinetics, area-under-curve estimates, etc. I've also dabbled in math modelling of infectious diseases.

Comment: @Deepak, sounds like a good combination, very impressive indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $y$ as a function of $x$ and use the chain rule and product rule. $(x\sin (y(x))'=x(\sin(y(x))'+x'\sin(y(x))=xy'(x)\cos(y(x))+\sin(y(x))$